# Node.js http get request produces different result from web browser

Tags: node.js

This is login form so unfortunately I don't have a working demo. I hope that I can explain fully what's happening.

I get this result from hurl.it:
[image]
and this is the entire header and body.
[image]

I try to simulate the same result using Node.js `request` module:

```
var request = require ('request');

request
  .get({
    uri: "https://app.bom.com/j_login_user",
    qs: {
      "email": "email",
      "password": "pass"
    },
    headers: {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "user-agent": "runscope/0.1",
      "connection": "keep-alive"
    }
  })
  .on('response', function(response) {
    log.info(response);
  });
```

However, the result is entirely different from the one hurl.it produce. Here is a pastebin of the response object, with response code 200 instead of 302: http://pastebin.com/rKEH0Uwr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` [by default handles redirects automatically](https://github.com/request/request/blob/ee4cfbbc66dc1bfb7481e79ab7ce51d4e0ba9038/README.md#super-simple-to-use), so you'll never see the 302 response code.

Comment: Thank you, that's great to hear. However, to continue working on the logged in site, I need cookies such as `arena_session_id`, `JSESSIONID`, etc. The returned object from `request` doesn't provide me with those cookies so I'm not sure how I can continue web scraping

Comment: `request` supports cookie jars. See the examples in [the documentation](https://github.com/request/request#examples).

Comment: I just send a `POST` multidatapart/form-data and was replied with code 302. Is this expected? I thought it will redirect by default

Comment: As mentioned in the `request` documentation, you need to set `followAllRedirects: true` if you want to follow redirects for non-GET requests.